# How to iterate over json Array having multiple json objects with different header

Tags: java, json

I am getting an json array from rest webservice in response which is like

```
 [{
"mutualFund":{"fundCode":"XYZ","fundName": "Funds - Global Income 
 Fund (G)-SGD","isin":"LU0882574725","sedol":"1234"}},

 {"brokers":{"fundID":"abcd","fundName":"Funds - Focus 
  Fund A-USD","isin":"LU0197229882","sedol":"6543"}
 }]
```

I am trying to iterate over all mutualFund arrays attributes to fetch their value. I have tried this code snippet but its returning error --"mutualFund do not exist". In my json file some objects are of mutualfund type and some are of other type with different attributes so I had to iterate and differentiate between both of them . So I cant use getJSONObject(i).

```
 JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response.getBody());
  for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
  JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject("mutualFund");
  }
```

Comment: Which json library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the classes and methods you're using, I'm assuming you use `org.primefaces.json` classes. **But even if you're using a different API, the logic will be basically the same.**

First of all, look at your JSON structure:

```
[
  {
    "mutualFund": {
      "fundCode": "XYZ",
      "fundName": "Funds-GlobalIncomeFund(G)-SGD","isin":"LU0882574725","sedol":"1234"
     }
  },
  {
    "brokers": {
      "fundID": "abcd",
      "fundName": "Funds-FocusFundA-USD","isin":"LU0197229882","sedol":"6543"
    }
  }
]
```

It's an array with 2 elements. The first element is an object with just one key (`mutualFund`) and its value (another object with `fundCode` and `fundName` keys). Note that the object **has** a `mutualFund` key, and you're trying to get it as if the object itself **was** a `mutualFund`. That's what causes the error.

So, to get all `mutualFund` objects, you need to check every element in the array, and for each element you must check if it has a `mutualFund` key. Then your code will be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    // get object i
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // check if object has mutualFund key
    if (jsonObject.has("mutualFund")) {
        // get mutualFund object and do something with it
        JSONObject mutualFund = jsonObject.getJSONObject("mutualFund");
        // do something with mutualFund object (you can get values for fundCode and fundName keys, etc)
    }
}
```

**Note**: if you're using a different JSON API, the methods names might differ (instead of `has`, some uses `containsKey`, or `get(key) != null`, but the logic to find `mutualFund` objects will be the same).

Comment: I am using org.json lib .

Comment: For `org.json` the code would be the same. Have you tested?